# Count a number of pdf files in every subfolder separately in batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

Under the path U:\test\0014*  I have 99 folders and each of them has respectively 2 subfolders MASTER and DERIVATIVE_COPY. With a following script I try to count the number of PDFs in MASTER folder. If there are only one .pdf file there I want to copy it to DERIVATIVE_COPY folder. IF there are 0 or >1 .pdf in MASTER I want only to show the number of them. This operation should be done for each of the 99 folders.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /R  U:\test\0014\*\MASTER %%i in (*.pdf) do (
set /a anzahl+=1
)

if !anzahl! EQU 1 ( echo !anzahl! ) 
if NOT !anzahl! EQU 1 ( echo !anzahl! ) 
pause
```

Comment: You cannot use a wildcard in the drive and path specification.

Comment: @Squashman than what can I use there to show that there are 99 folders in folder 0014

Comment: Use `for /D` to iterate all folders in `U:\test\0014`, hence to resolve the wild-card, which must be in the last path element only: `for /D %%j in ("U:\test\0014\*") do for %%i in ("%%~j\MASTER\*.pdf") do (set /A anzahl+=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"

for /f %%i in ('dir /ad /s/b "%sourcedir%\master*"') do IF /i "%%~nxi"=="MASTER" (
 SET /a found=0
 FOR %%x IN ("%%i\*.pdf") DO SET /a found+=1
 IF !found!==1 (
  XCOPY /y "%%i\*.pdf" "%%i\..\derivative_copy\" >nul
 ) ELSE (
  ECHO !found! .pdf files found IN "%%i"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

First, execute a `dir` to get a directory-list of the "files" names that start `master` in the specified tree. Use `/ad` to select only the directory-names. Accept only those names where the "name+extension" is `master` (disregarding case)

For each directory-name found, set `found` to `0` then increment `found` for each `.pdf` file found in the directory `%%i`.

If the resultant count in `found` is `1`, `xcopy` the file found to the destination subdirectory (which conveniently creates the subdirectory if it doesn't already exist), using `/y` to overwrite any existing file of the same name and `>nul` to make the process silent.

Otherwise, report the directoryname and count of files.

Comment: Magoo, I am not understanding how this is going to find all the 99 folders that the user needs to process.  The asterisk is the 99 folders in his example.

Comment: I think OP's `DERIVATIVE_COPY` directories are parallel to `MASTER` ("_each of them has respectively 2 subfolders _"), so I think you will need `XCOPY /y "%%i\*.pdf" "%%i\..\derivative_copy\" >nul`. Also, if the directory doesn't exist (OP says theirs will), won't it give the "file or directory" prompt?

Comment: @Squashman The first `FOR` command walks the directory tree looking for directories called `MASTER` and executes the pdf-counting logic in each one it finds.

Comment: This code will not work if there is a directory named `master` in the `source directory`.

Comment: @Squashman: The `dir` command lists each subdirectory named `master` below the starting directory. Pop an `echo %%i` into the outler loop to see...perhaps you missed the `/s` in the `dir` command?

Comment: @Magoo, I would not have expected that behavior out of the `DIR` command without using a wildcard.  But like I said, it will not work if there is a directory named master in the source directory.  Good update to your code.

Comment: @TripeHound: Yes, that's my understanding of the problem. The point of using `xcopy` instead of `copy` is that if you terminate the destination directoryname with a backslash then that directoryname will be created, so you don't get the prompt.. I see what you mean about the `..` though - corrected.

Comment: @Squashman : Yes - it's a little odd. I think the logic goes like if dir/s finds a match to a non-wild name, what's it supposed to do? Should it stop or should it list *that* subdirectory? If it doesn't find a match to a non-wild name, then it simply assumes that the request is to search all subdirectories for a match. I'm sure that this characteristic can be used for some useful purpose.

Comment: I tried your code and got an error "System can't find the path". My source directory is `SET "sourcedir=U:\test\0014"` . In Folder 0014 I have 99 subfolders and each of them has MASTER and DERIVATIVE_COPY. I don't understand how does your code go through all of these 99 folders.

Comment: Well, if `u:\sourcedir` doesn't exist on your system, that's exactly what will happen. Substitute `U:\test\0014` for `u:\sourcedir` and see what happens. (but perhaps you'd want to ECHO the `xcopy` command - and remove the `>nul` - temporarily until you're sure of what happens.)

Comment: @OP: ?? if your subdirectories are `u:\test\0014...` then you'd need to set `sourcedir` to `u:\test`. The code should work for `u:\test\0014\...`. The code I've posted is directly as I tested it on mys system with `.pdf` files placed in subdirectories of `u:\sourcedir`, eg. `u:\sourcedir\subdir6\master`